# C# Timer Functions?

Tags: c#, timer

I am working in C# 2010 and I have a Timer:

```
private Timer m_Timer;


void KA(string SendStuff, object State)
{

}

m_Timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(KA(DATA)));
```

I want this timer to call the function "KA", passing whatever "DATA" is to it.

DATA is a string

How would I pass using a timer information to the function "KA"?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use a delegate / lambda expression:

```
string stuff = "hi";
Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ => KA(stuff, null)));
```

**Edit:**

After consideration and feedback a cleaner and simplified version is:

```
string stuff = "hi";
Timer t = new Timer(state => KA(stuff, state));
```

Comment: Why the `_` (underscore) ? It should be `state => KA(stuff, state)`

Comment: both work - the OP wasn't interested in the state, just his `stuff` string so I didn't need the state as argument.

Comment: Intrigued question: What happens there if stuff is amended before the timer is triggered?

Comment: @pdr: since this creates a closure `stuff` would be evaluated at the time the timer is triggered. This might or might not be what OP wanted, it's certainly a side effect that might come as a surprise.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, thought that might be the case but wasn't entirely sure. Makes both answers valid in different circumstances. +1 and thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can make it more obscure by using @_ =>

Comment: @Hans I try to fit in some ASCII art whenever I can ;-) Although I do like to mark a "throwaway" parameter with an underscore, I guess it's personal preference.

Comment: @Hans: was that `@_` intentionally perl-ish? Your comment made my day!

Comment: Sorry, but he/she wants to solve the problem in C#, not C++ !

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
private Timer m_Timer;

void KA(object state)
{
    string data = (string) state;
}

m_Timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(KA), DATA);
```

Comment: Another example is here: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code460-working-with-timercallback-delegate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating this article that demonstrates in c# a generic polling component that runs at a specified interval and uses a background thread to perform the user action specified.

Sample usage:

```
IPoller poller = new UrlPoller(args[0], TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
IPolling pollingComponent = new Polling.Core.Polling(poller);
pollingComponent.SubscribeForPollingUpdates(PollingAction);
pollingComponent.Start();
```

For the code and complete sample see:

http://www.avantprime.com/blog/24/an-example-of-repeating-code-using-a-worker-thread-without-using-timers-c